# Using align in beamer with overlays

Tags: beamer, align

How can I get the align environment to play nicely with `beamer` overlays? As a simple example I would like

```
\begin{align*}  
    a = \frac{bc}{c}  
\end{align*}
```

on the first overlay and then

```
\begin{align*}  
    a = b  
\end{align*}
```

on the second, but I want the equal signs to line up for both. Using `beamer`'s `\overprint` environment, for example, the equal sign shifts between the two lines I guess because they are of different length.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\pause` is the only overlay command that really gives me trouble.  I am usually able to workaround with the overlay-aware `\only`, `\uncover`, `\alt`, etc.  Just make sure you don't put the alignment character `&` inside one of their arguments.

In this case we use a standard trick for alignment: make the smaller thing overlap and the larger thing invisible.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
    a &= \mathrlap{\alt<2->{b}{\frac{bc}{c}}}\phantom{\frac{bc}{c}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: looks pretty good--there's still some vertical jitter in your code, is there a way to take care of that too?

Comment: Uh yeah, I'm an idiot...just add \vphantom{\frac{bc}{c}} and its good to go. Great solution, thanks again!

Comment: @evencoil: or do both with `\phantom`.