# \alert within align in Beamer

Tags: beamer, amsmath

I am trying to use `alert` within the AMS-math `align` environment, so that sets of equations uncover sequentially and are highlighted. I would expect something like this to work:

```
\begin{align}
\alert<1>{a &= b+c} \\
\alert<1>{a &= b+c} \\ \pause
\alert<2>{a &= b+c} \\
\alert<2>{a &= b+c} \\
\end{align}
```

by highlighting the first two equations in the first slide and the next two in the next slide. I am doing something wrong? Or is there a different way to get this to work?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16148/using-align-in-beamer-with-overlays

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's explained in the Beamer manual, section 23.4:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align}
\uncover<1->{\alert<1>{a} &\alert<1>{= b+c} \\}
\uncover<1->{\alert<1>{a} &\alert<1>{= b+c} \\}
\uncover<2->{\alert<2>{a} &\alert<2>{= b+c} \\}
\uncover<2->{\alert<2>{a} &\alert<2>{= b+c} \\}
\notag
\end{align}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This leaves a vertical space at the end of the display, a `\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}` or so can remove it.

You can't say `\alert<1>{a&=b+c}` because this confuses the `align` scanning mechanism.

Comment: Thanks! This is great. Do you know if there is a more streamlined way of doing this? Or maybe a way to automate this process?

Comment: Is there anything like `\alert` just with different color? Something like `\exmple` or anything like that?